# How do I disable firefox's auto update (globally) via cli

Tags: firefox, selenium

**Background:**
I need to disable firefox's auto-update feature because my selenium tests fails on my **headless server** when firefox decides to update before selenium supports that version. I am also not the one who installed firefox on to this server. I believe it was through yum install firefox

**Server:**

- Fedora 19 Schrödinger’
- Linux
- kernel-release: 3.11.6-201.fc19.i686.PAE
- processor: i686
- platform: i386

**Actions Taken:**

```
$ cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/
```

(could not find a Profiles dir do I create one?)

```
$ firefox -v
```

(process:11171): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed

**Links I went to for info:**
I must be doing something wrong. I can't seem to understand how to do what I want from these links:

- developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options
- support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_finding-your-profile-without-opening-firefox
- kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager#Linux
- support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/877235

Comment: If the browser has been installed using the systems package management system then the browser cannot update itself. It has no file system permissions to do so.

Answer (score -1):

> There may have been a more direct method, but I created a "No Updates"
>   profile which has all auto-updating turned off, and rewrote the
>   shortcut to:

```
firefox.exe -P "No Updates"
```

Source:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/768901

Comment: Good god. The OP is talking about a _Linux_ system. And you refer to `firefox.exe`. Wow.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I miss something here. But I have no Linux system where a `firefox.exe` command does not lead to an error. Would you care to explain why I am wrong there? Thanks!

Comment: But why did you write that `.exe` then, if it does not make any sense in the answer? And why don't you fix that?