# disable auto update in firefox using linux command line

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, xvfb

I have been facing issues with auto updation of firefox on linux machine. I need a solution to disable auto update of firefox as i need to use firefox version below 41 to support my selenium version. I am writing a script to install and run Xvfb and firefox. Is there a way via command line to disable auto update of firefox so that i can add it to my script.

Similar question was posted earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174244/how-do-i-disable-firefoxs-auto-update-globally-via-cli) but there is solution explained. can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Software is (usually and preferably) installed and updated on Linux systems using the software package management system provided by the distribution. We do not know what distribution or system you use, so we cannot precisely answer this question. Check yourself, all those systems offer some "locking" feature that allows to "freeze" an installed package to a certain version.

Comment: solution https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/768901

Comment: @AnanthaRajuC I am using redHat machine. I already saw this link but could not understand much. that is why posted here.

Answer (score 0):

---

> I am using redHat machine

You can add an exclude line to /etc/yum.conf

```
exclude=firefox*
```

---

---